# Z-Transform, Transfer Function, Poles & Zeros

Tags: complex-numbers, signal-processing, z-transform

I've been working on a question that I'm now stuck on. I need to:

> Determine the transfer function and poles-zeros of:

$y[n]=0.5y[n-1]-0.25y[n-2]+x[n]$

So far I've carried out a z-transform in order to get the transfer function (but that's the easy bit)

\begin{equation}
H(Z)={1\over 1-\frac12{z^{-1}}+\frac14{z^{-2}}}.
\end{equation}

However I'm not sure what to do next. The mark scheme basically states:

> \begin{equation}{1\over(1-re^{j\theta})(1-re^{-j\theta})}\end{equation} where $r=0.5$ and $\theta=\frac\pi3$

What steps do I need to take to get from the transfer function to the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
H(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac12{z^{-1}}+\frac14{z^{-2}}}
\end{equation}

First pull through a $z^{-2}$ in the denominator and then move it up the the numerator

\begin{equation}
H(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^2-\frac12{z}+\frac14{}}
\end{equation}

For the poles, you have to find the roots of the quadratic $z^2-\frac12{z}+\frac14{}$. We can use the quadratic formula if we like;

$$
z_p = \frac{1}{4}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{4}\pm \frac{j\sqrt{3}}{4}=\frac{1}{2}e^{\pm j\pi/3},
$$
where the last equality is conversion to polar form of a complex number.
So you have
\begin{equation}
H(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z-\frac{1}{4}- \frac{j\sqrt{3}}{4})(z-\frac{1}{4}+ \frac{j\sqrt{3}}{4})}=\frac{z^2}{(z-\frac{1}{2}e^{ j\pi/3})(z-\frac{1}{2}e^{- j\pi/3})}
\end{equation}

The denominator shows a complex conjugate pair of poles, and the numerator shows a double-zero at $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you. As I was just typing out my next question on how to get from the form you've left it in to the final form I've actually worked it out. The fact that the $\frac12$ magically disappeared threw me!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
You need to put z in positive powers:
If you multiply $$H(z)$$ by $$\frac{z^2}{z^2}$$
You will get:
$$ H(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^2-0.5z+0.25}$$
In this form, it is easier to find the poles and zeroes.  You need to factor.  The denominator has two complex poles and numerator two real zeros.